# JFactory query to select field value if mulitple conditions are met

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, php7, jfactory

I'm basically trying to create a Joomla JFactory query to COUNT and SELECT data if a particular field's value meets my criteria.

In "myTable", I may have several records where `Field4` may either be `NULL` or equal to `YES` or `NO`.

Ideally, I'd like a single query that would return a COUNT of records where `Field1`, `Field2`, and `Field3` equal `$Field1`, `$Field2`, and `$Field3` ... AND then where `Field4` = `YES` or `NO`, I'd like it to echo the text `YES` or `NO`, depending on if one of the records meets that criteria.

This code kind of does what I want, but it only returns a value of `YES` when `Field4` equals `YES`.  And I have a previous query above it (`$db4` and `$query4`) that returns the COUNT that I want. Seems like there should be a more efficient and easy way to do this.

```
$db5 = JFactory::getDbo();
$query5 = $db5->getQuery(true);

$query5 = $db5
->getQuery(true)
->select(array('ID', 'Field4'))
->from($db->quoteName('myTable'))
->where($db->quoteName('Field1') . " = " . $db->quote($Field1))
->where($db->quoteName('Field2') . " = " . $db->quote($Field2))
->where($db->quoteName('Field3') . " = " . $db->quote($Field3))
->where($db->quoteName('Field4') . " = " . $db->quote('YES'));

$db5->setQuery($query5);
$result5 = $db5->loadResult();
$Field4 = $result5;
echo $Field4;
```

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tips to offer here.

1. You only need one connection object for your file.  Don't bother with multiple `$db` variables -- just keep re-using the same one. *Notice how your `quote()` and `quoteName()` method calls did not fail when they used an earlier `$db` variable.
2. Since your `Field4` column can only be `NULL`, `YES`, or `NO`, and you only want `YES` and `NO` values, then the simplest attack is to filter out the `NULL` values.
3. To make your code more "D.R.Y.", you can pass an array of clauses to the `where()` method.
4. `loadResult()` is appropriate if you want a single column value and have adequate WHERE logic to guarantee a maximum of one row in the result set.  If you might receive more than one row (and you only want to receive one column of data), then `loadColumn()` is appropriate.  If you intend to use `ID` and `Field4` as a single row, then use `loadRow()`. If you intend to generate a result set with potentially multiple rows and multiple columns then you will need to call a method that can produce a multidimensional result set such as `loadObjectList()` or `loadAssocList()`.

My recommended approach will look like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query5 = $db
    ->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->qn('Field4'))
    ->from($db->qn('myTable'))
    ->where([
        $db->qn('Field1') . ' = ' . $db->q($Field1),
        $db->qn('Field2') . ' = ' . $db->q($Field2),
        $db->qn('Field3') . ' = ' . $db->q($Field3),
        $db->qn('Field4') . ' IS NOT NULL',
    ]);
```

The output of `$query5` via `echo $query5->dump();` is:

> ```
> SELECT `Field4`
> FROM `myTable`
> WHERE `Field1` = '1' AND `Field2` = '2' AND `Field3` = '3' AND `Field4` IS NOT NULL
> ```

Note: If you wanted to cache the column quoting of `Field4` instead of calling `qn()` on it twice, you could save it as a variable.

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to explicitly write the `YES` and `NO` where conditions, you can use one of the two following techniques:

1. `andWhere()` with `OR` as the glue parameter.

   ```
    ->where([
        $db->qn('Field1') . ' = ' . $db->q($Field1),
        $db->qn('Field2') . ' = ' . $db->q($Field2),
        $db->qn('Field3') . ' = ' . $db->q($Field3),
    ])
    ->andWhere(
        [
            $db->qn('Field4') . ' = ' . $db->q('YES'),
            $db->qn('Field4') . ' = ' . $db->q('NO')
        ],
        'OR'
    );
   ```

   This will produce:

   > ```
   > SELECT `Field4`
   > FROM `myTable`
   > WHERE 
   > (`Field1` = '1' AND `Field2` = '2' AND `Field3` = '3') AND 
   > (`Field4` = 'YES' OR `Field4` = 'NO')
   > ```
2. or an element containing an `IN` clause in the original `where()` call.

   ```
    ->where([
        $db->qn('Field1') . ' = ' . $db->q($Field1),
        $db->qn('Field2') . ' = ' . $db->q($Field2),
        $db->qn('Field3') . ' = ' . $db->q($Field3),
        $db->qn('Field4') . ' IN (' . $db->q('YES') . ',' . $db->q('NO') . ')',
    ]);
   ```

   This will produce:

   > ```
   > SELECT `Field4`
   > FROM `myTable`
   > WHERE `Field1` = '1' AND `Field2` = '2' AND `Field3` = '3' AND `Field4` IN ('YES','NO')
   > ```

Comment: mickmackusa,  thank you very much for your response and assistance!  Sorry I'm so late getting back to you. Had a sudden death in the family and have been away from work for a couple of weeks. I will try your resolution as soon as I can.  Thanks again!